# Using facebook APIs locally

Tags: heroku, localhost, facebook-apps

i want to start making a facebook app and using the APIs, but i dont have a website to test anything out. how do i get it working on localhost or is it better to start using heroku for it and upload all my php files onto that

Answer (score 0):

Use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html,)

It's available for Windows, Linux and for Mac.

Comment: i have wamp installed and that is what i am doing the localhost with